# Rubber plant propagation, move to soil

Tags: propagation, ficus

I’m new here :)  I’ve been tasked with propagating my mom’s rubber plant when we chopped off the top. I started with leaf propagation in water but after about 6 weeks there were only a few little nodules but no roots. So I moved them each into perlite/tent and most leaves have been progressing well for the last 2 weeks.  I’ve never done this before so I’m a little nervous about the next step.

One of the leaves has new growth coming in, but has not developed even one root. How should I proceed with this? The new growth started around 5 weeks after cutting.

Another one has a good little cluster of roots and new growth as well. How do I know when it’s time to move to soil, and what’s the best way to transition?

Thanks for any help and please excuse my lack of knowledge.

[image][image]

Comment: I should add, each leaf is in its own separate container/tent on a north-facing kitchen window (frosted), in Florida. So it’s fairly warm and bright, but not direct. I’m in a shotgun apartment, so not many other options for placement.

Comment: Don't overthink it. What are roots for? They are there for stability and gathering supplies from the soil. So, if it has roots, give it soil.

Answer (score 3):

When the roots are a couple of inches long pot it up in a small pot.  If you can continue to keep the humidity high with a transparent tent.  Keep the plant in high diffuse light so it gets light but not too hot.